# Sum values for the same date in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that's tracking the duration of a particular activity over time. Imagine it looks something like this:

```
date     | start time | end time | duration 

5/21/18     10:00 AM    10:30AM        30
5/21/18     11:30 AM    12:30PM        60
5/21/18      2:00 PM     2:30PM        30
5/23/18     11:30 AM    12:30PM        60
5/24/18      9:30 AM    11:30AM       120
```

I want to make a chart with the dates along the X axis and the duration along the Y axis. However, I want each date to just be shown ONCE, with the TOTAL SUM duration for that date. So, the bar for 5/21/18 should be 120 min (i.e. the total of the three 5/21/18 entries), the bar for 5/22 should be 0 minutes (since there is no entry), and the bar for 5/23 should be 60 min.

If I make a chart as is, it treats each row as a separate entry (so there are three separate bars for each of the 5/21/18 entries), which doesn't work for my purposes since I want to combine entries with the same date, and have entries for in-between dates that have no entries.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add any missing dates in the series.
In this case there is only one day but it could just as easily be two, three or a month's worth of dates.

**Credit** for missing dates in series: "--Hyde", Google Docs Help Forum [Automatically Insert Missing Rows And Fill Values](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/os29s31TEjk).

*Assumption: the range shown in the question starts in cell A1 on a sheet named 'so_53684341'.*

1) Create a new data series, including any missing values
a) Create a new sheet.
b) Cell A1, insert `=arrayformula( { "Date"; datevalue("21/05/2018") + row(1:4) - 1 } )`.
c) Cell B1, insert `=arrayformula( {"Start time","End time","Duration"; if( len(A2:A), iferror( vlookup( A2:A, {datevalue(left(substitute(so_53684341!A2:A, " ", "-"), 10 ) ), so_53684341!B2:D }, column(so_53684341!B2:D2), false ), { "", "", 0 } ), iferror(1/0) ) } )`
This creates data in columns B, C and D. It duplicates the existing data on the original range. and puts a zero value in the Duration column for any non-existing date(s).
You can format the date column as appropriate.

2) Create a query to be used as the basis for the chart
a) Cell F1, insert `=query(A2:D5,"Select A, sum(D) group by A label (A) 'Date', sum(D) 'Duration' ")`
This creates a range F1:G5

3) Create a chart using the range F1:G5
Something like this

---

[image]